# NoMethodError - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems displaying data from a separate controller. I have a number of users, each with many pages. I've followed [this](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/wiki/Tutorial-%28Walkthrough%29) tutorial with a few minor adjustments.

The error that keeps appearing is:

```
NoMethodError in SitesController#show

undefined method `page' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000102452d30>
```

My routes.rb is as follows:

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users, :only => [:index, :show] do
    resources :pages, :shallow => true
  end
  match '/' => 'sites#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }
  root :to => "home#index"
```

And I have a sites controller:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @site = Site.find_by_name!(request.page)      
  end   
end
```

I've also tried:

```
def show
    @site = Site.find_by_name!(params[:site])      
end
```

Which gives a different error.

Am totally stuck trying to figure this out!

Looking forward to your assistance.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `request.page`

The `request` object is of the class [`ActionDispatch::Request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html), which does not have a `page` method.

To track down errors like this, you can try either looking at the docs or messing around in the debugger.

Try running your controller with `--debugger` enabled.

- If you are running Ruby 1.8, install the `ruby-debug` gem.
- If you are running Ruby 1.9, install the `ruby-debug19` gem.
- Add a `debugger` call here:

  ```
  class SitesController < ApplicationController
    def show
      debugger
      @site = Site.find_by_name!(request.page)      
    end   
  end
  ```
- Run your server with the `--debugger` option.
- See what `p request.page` does. I bet it will have an "undefined method" error, just you see when you try to view that controller action.
- If you do a `p request.class` you can find out what class the object is, and then look up the docs to see how to use it.